# MongoDB stuck at "admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017" in CentOs 32 bit server

Tags: mongodb

The `mongod` command gets stuck after the following line. I haven't changed any setting. I also encountered the problem saying "/data/db", solved it by creating the directory. Restarting doesn't have any changes.

```
  **mongod --help for help and startup options
     32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
     pid=5517 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit host=nxtgplus-test
     [initandlisten] 
     [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
     [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
     [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently off.
     [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
     [initandlisten] 
     [initandlisten] db version v2.4.14
     [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
     [initandlisten] build info: Linux buildvm-03.phx2.fedoraproject.org 3.19.5-200.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon
 Apr 20 19:51:56 UTC 2015 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
     [initandlisten] allocator: system
     [initandlisten] options: {}
     [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
     [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port
```

I am working on CentOS release 6.7 (Final) server. Please help me solve the above issue.

Comment: The server looks like it is working fine. It is waiting for connections on the default port 27017. What is it you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to start mongodb server using the command "mongod"

Comment: The server has started. In a new terminal window you can connect to it using the command `mongo`, which opens a Mongo shell.

Comment: The "mongo" command gave me the below error:MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14
connecting to: test
Mon Mar 28 14:37:10.991 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed

Comment: So you're running `mongod` in one window and then `mongo` in another and getting that error?

Comment: No I tried this on same terminal earlier. As you mentioned, I tried the command "mongo" on new terminal. The mongo shell opened and now I am able to work on mongo database. Thank you for the help.